# JSON schema failed to resolve $ref, Expected StartObject Bolean, got String

Tags: json, validation, schema, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

Subschema in another file can't be resolved by `$ref`

Error Message:
`Unexpected token encountered when reading value for '$ref'. Expected StartObject, Boolean, got String. Path 'properties.organization.items.properties.$ref'`

Root schema

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "$id": "https://example.com/schema_root.json",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "organization": {
            "description": "Organization information associated with the sample",
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                    "$ref": "organisation.json#"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The subschema is in the same directory in file `organisation.json`

```
{
    "$id": "organisation",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "Organisation",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "Name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Role": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to me that the root schema could locate the subschema. However, because of some data type discrepancy, it can't load the subschema. But I am not sure what the discrepancy is?

In the Error message `Expected StartObject.got String` I am not sure what `StartObject` is  and what the `String` refers to.

Comment: This might be a problem with the particular validator. Which library are you using?

Comment: I've tried several validators, including Python jsonschema, AJV . The error message is slightly different, but all point to the 'String' problem. I wonder if there's some data type restrictions in "$ref"

Comment: What happens when you remove the hash at the end of the `$ref` value? Additionally, the location of a schema in a file in a folder structure is generally not known or considered to an implementation. You must add or load in the other schemas you wish to reference before running the validation. Reference resolution works on the URI alone. The `$id` of your other schema needs to be a FULL URI. In this case, it would need to match the domain part of the referencing schemas base URI.

Comment: Removing hash didnt change. I tried to change the $id of the subschema to a URL "www.example.com/subschema.json" and ref to the "$id" value in the root schema "$ref":"https://www.example.com/subschema.json(#)" The error message is `cant resolve the reference 'https://...subschema.json' from id 'https://...subschema.json#'` Could it be something related to the last hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems.

1. There is an extension (`.json`) on the reference path, but not the identifier path.
2. References are resolved against the `$id` changing how you would identify the second schema.

Hopefully, this isn't too terse to follow, but here's what happens.

```
// From Root Schema
"$id":  "http://example.com/schema_root.json"
"$ref": "organization.json#"

// $ref resolves to ...
"$ref": "http://example.com/organization.json#"

// Expected $id
"$id": "http://example.com/organization.json"

// Actual $id
"$id":                    "organization"
```

The identifier from the reference doesn't match the `$id` in the second schema, so the validator can't find the schema it needs.